# Regex match string containing optional square brackets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I've got a RegEx which I'm using in a formula to match a string in a user entered cell. I want to allow the match to include `[]` (which are optional) but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a long RegEx already but if I do this test

`Cell A1 Contains test[test]`

`REGEXMATCH(A1, ""&A1&"")`

It fails with an 'invalid regex' error but removing the `[test]` works fine. So I guess I need a way of escaping the entire contents of `A1`. Hoping its a simple thing that someone can enlighten me to!

Thanks as ever

Comment: It is odd that you use cell A1 both for the regex expression *and* the tested string. I would have expected to see B1 (or A2) in either the first or second argument of `REGEXMATCH`. Are you sure you put that right?

Comment: Please explain what input you have. Are you saying you want to include A1 contents into a regex pattern?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear. I just made the regex above to see if I could work out whats going on; basically just testing A1 is A1 which should be true, but it is only true if there are no square brackets as the returned brackets become part of the regex (?). In the final regex it will actually be comparing to a range. I need it to compare the value of A1 as a string but with some further regex for excluding brackets etc.

Comment: [Edit] to include 5 sample inputs and  the expected output for each.

Answer (score 0):

Sheets' regex is eager:

```
=regexextract(A1,"(test|\[test\])")
```

should extract from A1 whichever of `test` and `[test]` is present (only `test` if both).

Comment: Thanks pnuts but I need it to return both if present. The square brackets data will not be present by itself mind.